# c++ OpenGL: Mesh only appears on bottom half of the window

Tags: c++, opengl

I have just begun learning OpenGL, and I think there is a problem with my index array formula.

I'm trying to render a square terrain using IBO. When I draw with `glDrawElements`, the result would only appear on the bottom half of the screen, all tightly packed in a rectangular shape, while when I use `glDrawArrays` it works out perfectly with a square shaped and centered mesh.

I load my vertex height values from a grayscale, here is how I load vertices and create indices:

**For vertices:** right to left, bottom to top

```
int numVertices = image.width() * image.height() * 3;
float rowResize = image.width() / 2;
float colResize = image.height() / 2;

GLfloat* vertexData;
vertexData = new GLfloat[numVertices];
int counter = 0;

for (float j = 0; j < col; j++){
    for (float i = 0; i < row; i++){
        vertexData[counter++] = (i - rowResize) / rowResize;
        vertexData[counter++] = (j - colResize) / colResize;
        vertexData[counter++] = image.getColor(i,j) / 255.0f;
    }
}
```

**For indices:** Trying to follow the order of {0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2...}

```
2     3
-------
|\    |
| \   |
|  \  |
|   \ |
|    \|
-------
0     1

int numIndices = (row - 1) * (col - 1) * 2 * 3;
unsigned short* indexData = new unsigned short[numIndices];

counter = 0;


for (short y = 0; y < col - 1; y++){
    for (short x = 0; x < row - 1; x++){
        // lower triangle
        short L_first = y*row + x;
        short L_second = L_first + 1;
        short L_third = L_first + row;

        //upper triangle
        short U_first = L_first + 1;
        short U_second = U_first + row;
        short U_third = U_second - 1;

        indexData[counter++] = L_first;
        indexData[counter++] = L_second;
        indexData[counter++] = L_third;

        indexData[counter++] = U_first;
        indexData[counter++] = U_second;
        indexData[counter++] = U_third;
    }
}
```

I initialized VAO, VBO and IBO, and then gen, bind, link data for each buffer object, and then unbind all.

In the game loop I have:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, 0);
//glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);    

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numVertices);
//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

Since drawing from vertices works and drawing from indices doesn't, what could be wrong with my indices generation?

Thank you for your help!

(Weird thing: I just tried with another grayscale image, and it worked well with both drawing from vertices`GL_POINTS` and indices`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`...welp)

**Pictures**

[Using glDrawArrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdER0.png)

[Using glDrawElements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LN89.png)

Comment: Pictures would be really nice.

Comment: Are you sure your vertex indices fit into an unsigned short? With just 65k vertices, you are limited to a base size of e.g. 256*256.

Comment: @derhass That's a good point, thank you! EDIT: it worked! I forgot to change the enum in drawing call! Thank you!!